# Reading line by line from text file in C++, how can I make sure the input is a double?

Tags: c++, file

I'm currently using a technique similar to file >> vec[i] to fill up an array with values from the lines of a file. However, how can I be sure that this will return an error message if the line it tries to read is not a number? It should be allowed to take ints and doubles, but not something like "lol" or 3,24,5.

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern is to *check* the result of the input operation:

```
double d;
if (file >> d) { vec[i] = d; }
else           { /* error (now you must handle this before trying again) */ }
```

If an error does occur, you have to decide on some policy for what to do next -- skip over it somehow, terminate the program, etc.

Comment: This doesn't fix an input like '2,4334nnngadfj4'. It just uses '2' instead.

Comment: @user2946291: True, but you'll see that on the next round. Alternatively, if you use linewise string streams, you can add `>> std::ws` and then check that there's nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can just check the fail bit after your read:

```
cin>>d;
if(cin.fail())
  // we failed! Print an error!
```

or like this:

```
if (not (cin>>d))
  // we failed! Print an error!
```

But that can be bothersome if you have a lot of reads, as you'll handle errors after each read.

Alternatively, you can turn on the option in `cin` that throws an exception on failure:

```
cin.exception(std::ios::failbit);
//...
cin>>d; // will throw on failure
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I be sure that this will return an error message if the line it tries to read is not a number?

A common technique is to set the stream bits to the exception mask after the input has been performed. Then you can perform cleanup (or rethrow the exception) as you like:

```
file.exceptions(std::ios_base::goodbit);

while (file >> x)
{
    // ...
}

try { file.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit  |
                      std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::eofbit); }
catch(std::ios_base::failure&)
{
    if (file.rdstate() & std::ios_base::failbit)
        // ...
    if (file.rdstate() & std::ios_base::badbit)
        // ...
    if (file.rdstate() & std::ios_base::eofbit)
        // ...
}
```